# Bash: just put all of stdout into specified variable

Tags: bash, pipe

Is there function like `setvar`?

So, can i write something like this:

```
cat ... | grep ... | sed ... | setvar VALUES

echo "$VALUES" | do-anything
```

I don't want write like:

```
VALUES="$(
    cat ... | grep ... | sed ...
)"
echo "$VALUES" | do-anything
```

Comment: What's wrong with the second form?  WHY don't you want to write it like that?  Except, of course, you would never use `cat` piped to `grep`.  Would you?  http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong with command substitution that you don't want to use it. Perhaps what you want is a function instead.

```
some_cmd () {
    cat ... | grep ... | sed ...
}

some_cmd | do-anything
```

In `bash` 4.2 or later, after running `shopt -s lastpipe` (and `set +m` to disable monitor mode, if necessary), you can use

```
... | read VALUE
```

to capture *the first* line of output in `VALUE`, or

```
... | { read line1; read line2; }
```

to capture a fixed number of lines, or

```
... | readarray -t VALUES
```

to capture multiple lines of output in the array `VALUES`, one line per element.

The `lastpipe` option is required; otherwise, the parameters set by `read` and `readarray` exist only in the subprocess created for the last element of the pipeline and will not be available to the shell following the pipeline.